# UNitofWork, edit method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to edit user with a repository and unitOfWork

This is my GenericRepository:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal LolaBikeContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(LolaBikeContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetWithRawSql(string query, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return dbSet.SqlQuery(query, parameters).ToList();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

And this is my UnitOfWOrk:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    private LolaBikeContext context = new LolaBikeContext ();
    private GenericRepository<UserProfile> userRepository;        

    public GenericRepository<UserProfile> UserRepository
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.userRepository == null)
            {
                this.userRepository = new GenericRepository<UserProfile>(context);
            }
            return userRepository;
        }
    }     


    public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

And now I want to edit a user, I have the method now like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="FirstName, LastName")]UserProfile userprofile)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string username = User.Identity.Name;
            // Get the userprofile
            //UserProfile user = unitOfWork.UserRepository.Get()   //db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
            unitOfWork.UserRepository.Update(userprofile);
            unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(userprofile);
            //user.FirstName = userprofile.FirstName;
            //user.LastName = userprofile.LastName;
            //user.Email = userprofile.Email;
            //user.Motto = userprofile.Motto;
            //user.PlaceOfBirth = userprofile.PlaceOfBirth;
            //user.HowManyBikes = userprofile.HowManyBikes;
            //user.BesideYourBeth = userprofile.BesideYourBeth;
            //user.NicestRide = userprofile.NicestRide;
            //user.WorstRide = userprofile.WorstRide;
            //user.AmountKmPerYear = userprofile.AmountKmPerYear;
            //user.AverageSpeed = userprofile.AverageSpeed;
            //user.AbleToChatWhileRiding = userprofile.AbleToChatWhileRiding;
            //user.PhoneNumber = userprofile.PhoneNumber;
            //db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Account");
        }
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes");
    }

    return View(userprofile);
}
```

But nothing will be changed.

Thank you

but If I try it with

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(UserProfile userprofile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                string username = User.Identity.Name;
                // Get the userprofile
               // UserProfile user = db.userProfiles.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName.Equals(username));
                unitOfWork.UserRepository.Update(userprofile);
                unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(userprofile);

                //user.FirstName = userprofile.FirstName;

                unitOfWork.Save();
                //db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Account");
            }

            return View(userprofile);
        }
```

I get this error:

```
{"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__UserProf__C9F28456B1DA0D25'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.UserProfile'. The duplicate key value is (savant).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

But there is only one username with the name savant

Comment: Do we need all the commented code to reproduce the problem? If not, please remove it. Do you get any error message? Did you try to debug it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just have sticked the comment. Because I want to show you how I did it before. But now if I remove all the properties and try to edit the  user with a unitOfWork the user will not besaved anymore. So is there a way I can use the properties, but then with the UnitOfWork?

Comment: Why you call db.SaveChanges() instead of unitOfWork.Save(). Is it teh same context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write this: `[Bind(Include="FirstName, LastName")]UserProfile userprofile` it means that your userprofile only takes those two values, you dont't have an ID so when you do the Update method call, `dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);` cant attach entity which doesn't have an ID. You have to forward ID parameter also from frontend... Or you can get ID in some other way but the point is that element without ID set can't be attached.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But If I do it without genericrepository, just with: db... then it works

Comment: Look at Mike Vitiki comment above.

Comment: Why are you doing unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(userprofile) if you just want to update entry?

Comment: You should remove the Insert line.